# when setting up devecostudio freshers need to register as a huawei developer?its showing "age requirement not met while registering ,what to do now?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

While setting up DevEco Environment, do we freshers also need to register as Huawei Developer? It's showing "age requirement not met" while registering, What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

> While setting up DevEco Environment, do we freshers also need to register as Huawei Developer?

You do not need to register a Huawei developer account to set up the DevEco Environment， But need to register a Huawei developer account to use the simulator and run cases.

For details, you could  refer to [this Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/tools_overview-0000001053582387) to quickly set up the IDE environment.